# How to refresh access token. Without opening graph API explorer ? In facebook GraphAPI

Tags: api, facebook, graph, instagram

According to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/reference/refresh_access_token/ , to refresh a long term access token , which you can get from user access token.

I am calling GET request on URL

```
https://graph.instagram.com/refresh_access_token
  ?grant_type=ig_refresh_token
  &access_token={long-lived-access-token}
```

It returns

```
Sorry, this content isn't available right now
```

Is there any other way by which I can refresh access_tokens automatically by calling GET requests on URLs.

Comment: Please edit the question and provide more clear information's, `graph.instagram.com` is no longer available to use. what token do you want to refresh a fb_user token or a page token?

Comment: I have edited, the token is long term user access token, you can get short term user access token from graph api explorer, then from that token you can find a long term access token.

Answer (score 2):

If you are already have the `Long-lived access token` then you can't refresh it manually

When user login using facebook login button what you get is a short lived access token you use this endpoint to get a long lived access token

```
curl -i -X GET "https://graph.facebook.com/{graph-api-version}/oauth/access_token?  
    grant_type=fb_exchange_token&          
    client_id={app-id}&
    client_secret={app-secret}&
    fb_exchange_token={your-access-token}"
```

after you got the long lived token it's will refresh once per day automatically if the user is using your app means the token is being used, if the token is not being used after 60 days the user must go through the login flow again in order to get a new token [read more here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/refreshing/#:%7E:text=long%2Dlived%20User,a%20new%20token.)